# how to use the qml DelegateModelGtoup resolve function

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to qt/qml,I want to use `DelegateModel` add element dynamicly.But I found the element's  `isUnresolved` property is always true.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.2
Rectangle {
    width:1280
    height:720
    ListModel{
        id:delegateModel
        ListElement{
           name:'USA'
        }
        ListElement{
           name:'JP'
        }
        ListElement{
           name:'UK'
        }
        ListElement{
           name:'ZH'
        }
        ListElement{
           name:'GEO'
        }
    }
    ListView{
        id:view
        anchors.fill: parent
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        displaced: Transition {
            id:displacedTransition
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y";easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }
        remove: Transition {
            id:removeTransition
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y";easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }
        model:DelegateModel{
            id:visualModel
            model:delegateModel
            delegate:Item{
                width:256
                height:720
                Rectangle{
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    width:256*0.8
                    height:width
                    radius:width/2
                    color:Qt.rgba(1,0.4,0.4,0.6)
                    Text{
                       anchors.centerIn:parent
                       text:name
                    }
                    MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: {
                            visualModel.items.insert(index,{name:"prev"+name})
                            console.log(visualModel.items.get(index).isUnresolved)
                            visualModel.items.resolve(index,index)
                            console.log(visualModel.items.get(index).isUnresolved)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert data into `delegateModel` instead of `visualModel.items` and the item is always resolved.

Comment: yes,you are right.but I just want to know how to use `resolve` function.thanks